# Scoring overlay in Corona

Tags: lua, overlay, coronasdk, scoring

im new to Corona and im having a bit of a problem with my scoring system. See what happens is that when you begin the game, the score starts at 0, which it should. When the player gets a score, it should increment by two. Well it does increment its just that instead of the number 0 changing to the number 2, what i get is the number 0 and then the number 2 ON TOP of 0. So it overlays. I couldnt find any posts that actually addressed this issue, so i think im doing something wrong here. Any help? Or just point me in the right direction? Thank in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with your code is that everytime you call displayScore() function it creates another newText because you always calls

`local scoreText = display.newText("Score: ", 415, 100, native.systemFont, 50)`.

try to declare the `scoreText` outside the function `displayScore()` just like this

```
local scoreText = display.newText("Score: ", 415, 100, native.systemFont, 50)

function displayScore()
    scoreText:setTextColor(255, 255, 255)
    scoreText.text = scoreText.text = "Score: "..score

end
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed answer. I actually understand what you mean now that you explained it, but when i tried that code, its not showing me anything on the screen at all. I think the problem may be with this:  scoreText.text = scoreText.text = "Score: "..score Ive been trying to search around for a code that will display my variable without declaring it as a newText but i cant find anything. Also, print doesnt work for some reason?

Comment: try making your coordinates code of your display.newText like this
local scoreText = display.newText("Score: ", 100, 100, native.systemFont, 50)   i think the problem is that you cannot see it because the y axis position is beyond your screen size

Comment: No, i can see it on my screen now. I tried a different approach, function displayScore()
 scoreText.text = ("Score: " )..score
 score = score + 2
end


timer.performWithDelay( 1000, displayScore)
The problem now is, when the player restarts the game, on the first chop of the fruit, it still says 0. What do you think could be wrong? Thanks so much for your patience with me. :)

Comment: I fixed it now, i just placed the timer.performWithDelay( 1000, displayScore) in main().

Comment: so is your problem solved you can accept the answer if one of the it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this and change your code:

```
score = 0
local scoreText = display.newText(score, 100, 100, native.systemFont, 50)
scoreText:setTextColor(255, 255, 255)

function displayScore()
    --[[ The problem was here. You are creating new label over and over in 
          your code. So, you need to either remove the old label and add 
          new using 'scoreText:removeSelf()' or just update the code --]]
    score = score + 1
scoreText.text = score
end
Runtime:addEventListener("tap",displayScore)
```

Keep Coding............ :)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. :) How do i go about updating the code?

Comment: Hi, so i did it like your code, but the problem is every time i "tap" the screen, it adds a score. I only want it to add a score when the user slashes an object in the function chopFruit. How would i go about doing that?

Comment: I've added the last line for your testing purpose. Comment that line and call the function as: 'displayScore()' when you need to update the score.